# Notational problems while proving for every integer $m$ that $3m^5$ is even.

Tags: real-analysis, notation, first-order-logic

I'm having trouble understanding the notation in this proof. The proof begins with 2 lines. I will try to explain the lines, and I would like if you could tell me if I'm correct.

$\forall m\in\mathbb{Z}\ \ p(m) \implies p(3m^5)$

and

$p(m) \equiv \exists y\in\mathbb{Z}\ \ m = 2y $

The 1st line sends all integers $m$ to a condition $p(m)$. Let's say for example $m = 1$. In line 2, we're asserting that there exists an integer $y$ such that $1 = 2y$, which is false. But a false antecedent leads to a true implication, so we can move onto the next integer, $m = 2$, and so on and so forth.

Is this correct?

Comment: Nothing is being sent anywhere. The two lines simply say that if $m$ is even then so is $3m^5$.

Comment: But if you had to manually check all the values of $x$ to verify this, then you'd be sending values around. Like a computer. Right?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with computer programming.

Comment: A computer could prove or disprove this statement by brute force, if the set was finite.

Comment: In a nutshell, the formula says: "if $m$ is Even, so is $3m^5$" (that is true).

Comment: *If the set was finite*... but it isn't.  In any case... *if m is even* then we know that there is some $y$ such that $m=2y$ in which case $3m^5 = 3(2y)^5=2(48y^5)$ is a multiple of two.  Q.E.D.  If you prefer to use analogies of computers and .forEach loops... I suppose go ahead, but keep in mind infinite sets and in particularly uncountably infinite sets the analogy breaks down rapidly.

Comment: I suppose the most important thing I'm trying to ask is that when $m$ is odd, $p(m)$ is false, right?

Comment: Yes, if $m$ is Odd, this means that there is **no** $y$ such that $m=2y$ and thus $P(m)$ is false. Thus, as you said, it follows that $P(m) \to Q$ is true, for $Q$ whatever, and specifically: $P(m) \to P(3m^5)$ is true.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The second line is the definition (or maybe a repetition of the definition) of the predicate $p$. It says that $p(m)$ means '$m$ is even'.

The first line is the claim you are going to prove: for every integer $m$, *if* $m$ is even, *then* $3m^5$ is even as well.

(Note by the way that your title says that 'while proving for every integer $m$ that $3m^5$ is even'. That is wrong.)